# smallest mysql type that accommodates single decimal

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, types

Database newbie here. I'm setting up a mysql table. One of the fields will accept a value in increment of a 0.5. e.g. 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, .... 200.5, etc.

I've tried `int` but it doesn't capture the decimals.

```
`value` int(10),
```

What would be the smallest type that can accommodate this value, considering it's only a single decimal.

I also was considering that because the decimal will always be 0.5 if at all, I could store it in a separate boolean field? So I would have 2 fields instead. Is this a stupid or somewhat over complicated idea? I don't know if it really saves me any memory, and it might get slower now that I'm accessing 2 fields instead of 1

```
`value` int(10), 
`half` bool,  //or something similar to boolean
```

What are your suggestions guys? Is the first option better, and what's the smallest data type in that case that would get me the 0.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [`DECIMAL(P,S)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) type.

For that, P is the precision and S is the scale. You can think of P as how many digits there are in total (both before and after the decimal point), and S as how many of the digits are after the decimal point.

So for instance, to store from -999.99 to 999.99, you'd need 5 digits of precision and a scale of 2, therefore you'd use `DECIMAL(5, 2)`.

In your case, you'd need a `DECIMAL(n, 1)`, where n is how many digits you need before the decimal point + 1 for the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DECIMAL(N,1)
```

Where `N` is the precision that represents the max number of significant digits that can be stored.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `DECIMAL`, you could store the tenfold of the value in an `INT` column (which I would *think* could be more efficient.)

- 0.5 => 5
- 201.5 => 2015
- etc.