# How to store a number with one decimal

Tags: database, floating-point, decimal

I need to store a combination of numbers into one database. A number with one decimal to be exact.

For example 1.2

I tried storing it using float. I see here in phpadmin is says float(8,2)
I tried to store 1.2, but the database gives me: 1.2000000476837

How can i get a one decimal number stored?

Comment: See this link for your answer 
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708008/smallest-mysql-type-that-accomodates-single-decimal

Comment: what kind of database? what programming language? how did you store it?. Float would probably be right, you just need to decide how to print it out. For example using %.1f with printf will give you one decimal number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store it using decimal(8,2) and see what you get from database

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: oh,got it.I am a new guy here and thank you for tell me all this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(1.222222222222, 1, 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 1))
```

OP: 1.2

You have alter your field datatype as decimal(x,1)

```
The maximum value a DECIMAL (5, 1) can hold is : 9999.9

The maximum value a DECIMAL (5, 2) can hold is : 999.99

The maximum value a DECIMAL (5, 3) can hold is : 99.999

The maximum value a DECIMAL (5, 4) can hold is : 9.9999
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the DECIMAL(P,S) type.

In your case, you'd need a `DECIMAL(n, 1)`, where n is how many digits you need before the decimal point + 1 for the decimal.